# SQL split a colon and Space from the Description Field/Column

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server ,One of my table has a text column named `description` and it contains the value in one particular row as

```
"addText : PCS 10.17.16.5 is activated notificationId : 429 probableCause : TransmitFailure(54) severity : severe(3) "
```

From the mentioned Text I need to fetch the value for the each key  seperately and display the result in a seperate column .

I used the below SQL Query but it is not working !

```
SELECT  SPLIT(description,"_") FROM [dbo].[Stg_Event]
# (or)
SELECT  Split(description,':') FROM [dbo].[Stg_Event]
```

please help..Thanks in Advance

Comment: which values do you want to fetch? 
Col1: PCS...
Col2: 429 probableClause
...?

Comment: Check the duplicate link.  If it doesn't meet your needs then leave a comment here why this is the case.

Comment: please give me an example

Comment: Give example of result

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is there anyway we can remove the accepted answer from that post?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint No, but if you strongly disagree you may choose to downvote it, or maybe add a comment.

Comment: I don't like the most upvoted answer either, a `WHILE` loop is an awful way to split a string in SQL Server. Using the XML replacement is a far better way. personally, I think we need to stop using that Question as the duplicate, it's a bad example.

Comment: Thank ! I need the Output from the Description Column 
addText : PCS 10.17.16.5 is activated       notificationId : 429 probableCause : TransmitFailure(54)        severity : severe(3)" Here all are in the same row but I need all the values alone to be displayed in a seperate column like mentioned below.
OutPut:
Column1     Column2       Column3     Column4

Comment: Thanks  stylefish ! I need the Output from the Description Column 
addText : PCS 10.17.16.5 is activated       notificationId : 429 probableCause : TransmitFailure(54)        severity : severe(3)" Here all are in the same row but I need all the values alone to be displayed in a seperate column like mentioned below.
OutPut:I will Explain the result for 2 values alone from the mentioned Description Column.
                                           
PCS 10.17.16.5 is activated  as column1 ,  429 as column 2     ,           TransmitFailure(54) as column 3